# Multiples labels one on top another on bottom

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, point

How can i do this labels? A labels in top another in bottom in the same layer?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can write a labelling expression with the vbnewline command (with the VBscript parser). This would look like the following

```
[Field1] &vbnewline & [Field2]
```

[image]

As a remark, there are plenty of formatting examples [here](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1104/files/vbscript_label.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by changing the default label method to "Define classes of features and label each class differently".
Here are the steps:

1. Change the method to "Define classes of features..."
2. Add a new class
3. select a new class, default or the new one
4. select the label field [for up/down]
5. Change the placement properties>label placement>position [Northwest/Southwest]
6. repeat step 3 with alternative class
7. select the alternative label field
8. repeat step 5 with alternative position option.
   For more control, you can use Label manger (Customize>toolbars>Labelling).

   [image]